# Cocos2d 1.0 to cocos2d 2.0 source port

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have below function in cocos2d 1.0, it is not compiling in cocos2d 2.0.

Anyone help me to get same for cocos2d 2.0.

```
void ccFillPoly( CGPoint *poli, int points, BOOL closePolygon )
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, poli);
    if( closePolygon )
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points);
    else
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cocos2d 2.x provides functions for drawing OpenGL ES primitives. The header file is *CCDrawingPrimitives.h*:

```
/** draws a solid polygon given a pointer to CGPoint coordiantes, the number of vertices measured in points, and a color.
*/
void ccDrawSolidPoly( const CGPoint *poli, NSUInteger numberOfPoints, ccColor4F color );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this draws rect, but opacity is not applied, any idea how to apply 50% opacity to this primitive?

Comment: the ccColor4F has an alpha component, has it not?

Comment: I set last parameter ccc4f(128, 128, 128, 128), but alpha is always opaque even if I set 128..not varying..any thoughts?

Comment: ccc4f takes float parameters, from 0.0 to 1.0. Alpha 1.0 - fully opaque, 0.0 - fully transparent. For 50% alpha you'd want 0.5.